# Issue with defining a graphQL schema for an object

Tags: graphql, schema

I have an object with some properties but unable to define the schema. 
Structure of the object

```
{
    "1": {
        average: 40,
        count: 15
    },
    "2": {
        average: 11,
        count: 2
    },
    "3": {
        average: 30,
        count: 2
    }
}
```

My schema

```
const typeDef = gql`
 type Query {
   scoreByRank: Count
}

type Count {
  "1": obj
  "2": obj
  "3": obj
}

type obj{
average: Int
count: Int
}
`;
```

But this query is failing because of the object prop with "1", "2" etc. Is there a better way to build this schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL field names must follow certain rules. Specifically `/^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`. As you can see, a field name must not start with a number 0-9. Certain field names might be inconvenient for a consumer of your GraphQL API depending on what languages they are using. The field name restrictions are defined so that most common languages can easily use the data provided by a GraphQL API.

The recommended solution is to follow the rules and come up with better field names, like `_1`, `two` or `field3`.

You could return an array instead of an object, but there is currently no easy way of enforcing a specific length for an array. On top of that, the indexing of an array would start at 0 rather than 1.

You could define a custom scalar for your object, but then you would lose the ability to leave out unnecessary fields and it would require far more convoluted code to work. As such, I would consider it bad practice. Only do it if you're dealing with an inflexible and opaque third party application that leaves you no other way.

Comment: thanks! yeah, I had to change my field from "1" to "something1".